# Endian-independent data encoding

Tags: c++, endianness

I am implementing an endian-independent data encoding (writing to a buffer) like this:

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < sizeof(value); ++i)
{
  buffer[i] = static_cast<uint8_t>(value >> 8 * i); // not optimized
}
```

gcc and clang both unroll the loop, but the first (uncommented) line is being compiled to this assembly:

```
mov    eax,edi
mov    BYTE PTR [rsp],dil
sar    eax,0x8
mov    rsi,rsp
mov    BYTE PTR [rsp+0x1],al
mov    eax,edi
sar    edi,0x18
sar    eax,0x10
mov    BYTE PTR [rsp+0x3],dil
mov    BYTE PTR [rsp+0x2],al
```

But it is basically an assignment from value to *buffer on little-endian architectures. Is there any way to trick the compiler to transform this to a simple assignment instead of 4 byte moves (when compiling for little endian targets)?

PS. I know I could make a runtime check (branch) or check the endian at compile-time (via __BYTE_ORDER__ macro), but I want to do it without the checks (with shifts)

Comment: if value is `int` >> operator is UB.

Comment: This is what htonl is for...

Comment: change everything to network endian before encrypting, that has been working well for many protocols

Comment: @Raxvan - Only for negative values.

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth yes, only for negative values.

Comment: @Raxvan value is uint32_t

Comment: @Aconcagua that does not answer my question. I need to convert (for example some integers in RTMP are little-endian) integer to little-endian and htonl would require me to convert it back to little endian (which is more instructions than I currently have).

Comment: If you can compile-time check for endianess, you could do an `#ifdef` compiler switch which simply does a 32 bit assignment if endianess between CPU and network matches. Overall, this sounds like pre-mature optimizations though. The CPU will perform 4 non-conditional assignments incredibly fast.

Comment: int + >> UB? No, implementation defined! int + << is, if overflow occurs.